# How to find how many atoms have to decay to get some amount of power?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, power, radioactivity

How do I get the power when there is no charge, or anything else given in the question?
Is there a power formula that I'm not aware of? Please help!

> A nucleus of plutonium-238 ($^{238}_{\ \ 94}$Pu) decays by emitting an $\alpha$-particle to produce a new nucleus X and 5.6 MeV of energy. The decay is represented by $${}^{238}_{\ \ 94}\rm Pu \to X + \alpha+5.6\:MeV.$$ Calculate the number of plutonium-238 nuclei that must decay in a time of 1.0 s to produce a power of 0.15 W.

Comment: "there is no energy given in the question" - maybe you should read the question more carefully, particularly the part that says "to produce 5.6MeV of energy".

Comment: On a housekeeping note, please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are told the energy released by one decay is $5.6$ MeV (mega [electronvolts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt)). A power of $0.15$ Watts is $0.15$ Joules per second. The only missing piece is the conversion factor between MeV and Joules.

Comment: What formula do I use once I convert it?

Comment: what formula do I use?

Comment: @VirejDasani Read the Wikipedia article that I linked to, or just google "MeV Joules conversion".